# why getTransformLockFlags is mapped method, it still have to work with for loop

Tags: maxscript

i got the below from maxscript official tutorial:

```
getTransformLockFlags <node> -- mapped
```

when i try the code `getTransformLockFlags selection` in the listener window, it gives an error:

-- Type error: Call needs function or class, got: undefined
-- MAXScript callstack:
--  thread data: threadID:4324

---

--  [stack level: 0]
--  In top-level

but if i use `getTransformLockFlags $`, or `for i in selection do getTransformLockFlags i`,it works fine.

This really confused me, because if the getTransformLockFlags method is mapped, which means it should work with collection directly, but from my situation, it seems only work with single node, not the selection.

thanks in advance if you have any idea!

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an error in the documentation as getter functions don't really make sense for collections in the context of MAXScript.

Comment: so its like..if a function is not mapped or a kind of mapped getter function  that will not make sense for collections?

Comment: Not mapped, on my max install it specifically complains that it wants a node argument.